# How to access and modify the mouse cursor outside of the UI thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, cursor-position, mouse-cursor

I'm writing a macro program, and have almost everything set up expect mouse control. The problem it that the logic is running separate from the UI thread, and that I don't know how to convert the mouse from the UI thread to the new one.
This is the error I get without any invoking.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

I tired to remedy this by invoking the Cursor, but it is not invokable it seems.
Is there any way to disable thread safety and would that even be a good idea?

```cs
if (Cursor.Current.Handle.InvokeRequired) //and other variations of it
   this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.Cursor = new cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle)));
else this.Cursor = new cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
```

Give the error

```
'IntPtr' does not contain a definition for 'InvokeRequired' and no accessible extension method 'InvokeRequired' accepting a first argument of type 'IntPtr' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Why are you running the logic in a background thread? Couldn't you isolate any non-UI, long running operation, and run only this in a background thread?

Comment: Are you in _Windows Forms_ or in _WPF_?

Comment: @ZorgoZ Windows forms.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias The logic is running in a background thread so it does not lock up the main UI thread. It can run in an infinite loop if a check mark is checked, and that would lock the UI.

Comment: Is it equally possible than an infinite loop will run in the background thread, or it's only an issue for the UI thread?

Comment: This is a program for macros, so one of the use cases is to press a key for infinity or till it get's an interrupt signal. The background thread, on which this action is performed on, can and will probably run an infinite loop till told otherwise. That's why I run it in a separate thread so UI does not lock up and I can still listen to the interrupt signal.

Answer (score 1):

The context belongs to the `Form`, not the cursor. That means you need to test for invocation on the form instance. But there is an other option though: grab the synchronization context itself.

```
var f = new Form();
var ctx = WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current;
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

Action a = () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        f.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
    };


Task.Run(async () => {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    ctx.Post(_ => a(), null);
});


Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    if (f.InvokeRequired) f.Invoke(a); else a();
});

f.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Action and async methods, so l hope I got this right. You create a new form then run an function "a" to set the cursor. But I don't get how you used  "if (f.InvokeRequired) f.Invoke(a); else a();" to get the cursor.

Comment: @RedXRed those are just for demonstration. The action is just the code you want to execute in the UI thread context. I created an action to avoid repeating the same code. And the Task is just fo forcing the code to run on the tread pool. This snippet actually runs in LinqPad.